# FormData push item in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, odata, form-data

I am trying to get values in a List using FormData but the list is always `null`.

```csharp
public List<OptionAns> Answerlst { get; set; }
```

```js
var formData = $('#submitform').serializeArray();

$('#customFields .optionAns').each(function (index) {
  formData.append("Answerlst[" + index + "].Id", $(this).attr('id'));
  formData.append("Answerlst[" + index + "].Value", $(this).val());
});

$("#submitform").validate({
  submitHandler: function (form) {
    var params = $.extend({}, doAjax_params_default);
    params['url'] = BaseUrl + 'odata/Questions';
    params['requestType'] = "POST";
    params['data'] = formData;
    params['successCallbackFunction'] = ajaxSuccess;
    params['errorCallBackFunction'] = ajaxError;
    doAjax(params);
    return false;
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using FormData at all? It seems a needless complication when you aren't sending any binary data in the request. I'd suggest removing it.

Comment: 1st. It seems your write C# code and js code together. `formData.append("Answerlst[" + index + "].Id", $(this).attr('id'));`. This won't work. 2nd. Where is the `list` you said ?

Comment: One question have multiple option answer so I want to pass option list with question data so for that i creating answerlist but not getting data in c#, I use  Odata api for save data. also i use formData.push that also not working for me.

Comment: @hyjiacan I create list object like public List<OptionAns> Answerlst { get; set; } in viewmodel in c# side.

Comment: I also use `public class QuestionAnswerVM
    {
        public IDictionary<string, string> dictionary { get; set; }
}` but not waorking

Comment: What `$('#customFields .optionAns').each(function (index) {
  formData.append("Answerlst[" + index + "].Id", $(this).attr('id'));
  formData.append("Answerlst[" + index + "].Value", $(this).val());
});` used for ? It does not like any MVC syntax.